# Why I receive NPE in partial view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have this partial view:

```
@model HesteIndex.Models.HorseModels

@if (Model != null)
{
    <a href="car-details.html">
        <img src="@Model.Pictures[0].MediaPath" alt="offer car">
        <div class="entry-label">
            <h4>@Model.Name</h4>
            <span class="price-tag">@(Model.PriceIndex == "0 - 0" ? Model.FixedPrice.ToString("#,###") : Model.PriceIndex) DKK</span>
        </div>
        <div class="entry-overlay" style="display: none;">
            <ul class="car-list-details">
                <li>@Model.Gender</li>
                <li>@Model.Color</li>
                <li>@Model.YearOfBirth</li>
                <li>@Model.Dressage</li>
                <li>@Model.Jump</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </a>
}
```

and I call it like:

```
<ul class="offer-small list-content">
            @if (ViewBag.RandomHorses != null)
            {
                foreach (HesteIndex.Models.HorseModels horse in (List<HesteIndex.Models.HorseModels>)ViewBag.RandomHorses)
                {
                <li>
                    @Html.Partial("_HorseSmallAd", horse);
                </li>
                }
            }
        </ul>
```

I don't understand why on `{` after `@if (Model != null)` in my partial I receive NPE:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

But I am 100% sure that I do not pass null object model (I have made debug and even printed out some horse properties where I call partial).

Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: check Model.Pictures has any element, what if it's empty and you are trying to call Model.Pictures[0].MediaPath, that's likely reason as per as i am concerned

Comment: `Model.FixedPrice` is nullable?